# mongo replication not happening

Tags: mongodb

I setup master/slave replication of mongodb on EC2. But I see not replication happening. When I do "show dbs" on master, it shows all dbs expected.

But when I do the same on replica, it does not show me any db.

Please help me troubleshoot.

```
rs.config()
{
    "_id" : "ittw",
    "version" : 1,
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "host" : "ip-10-304-48-93:27017"
        }
    ]
}

rs.config()
{
    "_id" : "ittw",
    "version" : 2,
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "host" : "domU-17-31-19-16-88-5F:27017"
        },
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "host" : "ec2-50-321-52-908.compute-1.amazonaws.com:27017"
        }
    ]
}



rs.status() // replica
{
    "set" : "ittw",
    "date" : ISODate("2013-08-12T06:55:57Z"),
    "myState" : 1,
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "name" : "$ip:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 1,
            "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
            "uptime" : 356039,
            "optime" : Timestamp(1375934685, 1),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2013-08-08T04:04:45Z"),
            "self" : true
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}



rs.status()  //Master
{
    "set" : "ittw",
    "date" : ISODate("2013-08-12T06:57:19Z"),
    "myState" : 1,
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "name" : "PRI_IP:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 1,
            "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
            "uptime" : 356543,
            "optime" : Timestamp(1376289725, 1),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2013-08-12T06:42:05Z"),
            "self" : true
        },
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "name" : "REP_IP:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 1,
            "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
            "uptime" : 355869,
            "optime" : Timestamp(1375934685, 1),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2013-08-08T04:04:45Z"),
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2013-08-12T06:57:17Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
            "pingMs" : 1
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like what you have done is run `rs.initiate()` on both the primary *and* the secondary server.

In this case the outcome is that you have two **different** replica sets called `ittw` rather than a single replica set with replication.  The primary knows about both nodes, but the "secondary" you setup is also configured as a primary for a replica set only containing itself.  This definitely won't work.

As per the instructions on [Deploying a replica set](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/), you should only run `rs.initiate()` on the primary, and then use `rs.add("hostname:port")` to add secondaries to the same replica set.

To fix up your dud secondary to a clean state, you should:

- stop the secondary using `db.shutdownServer()` or appropriate command like `service mongodb stop` (depending on how you installed MongoDB)
- remove the files in the `dbpath` directory for the secondary
- restart the secondary
- use the `mongo` shell to connect to the primary, and `rs.add()` your secondary

If all is well you should see consistent `rs.status()` information on the primary and new secondary.

Answer (score 1):

Have you run the rs.initiate command to kick it all off?

[Docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/rs.initiate/)

Also how do you have your replset configured? Is it a single master and a single slave? Do you have a second secondary or an arbiter to provide quorm and ensure clean failover?

Comment: rs.initiate()
{
 "info" : "try querying local.system.replset to see current configuration",
 "ok" : 0,
 "errmsg" : "already initialized"
}

Comment: 1 master + 1 slave

Comment: It looks like you have a split brain i.e. both nodes think they are primary. Have you tried rs.stepdown() on one of the nodes [Docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/rs.stepDown/)

Comment: Also I see you have two versions of rs.config. Have you run rs.reconfig using the newest version? [Docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/rs.reconfig/)

Answer (score 0):

I have correct this problem with the 2 parameters in the config file:

```
net.http.enabled:                "true"
net.http.RESTInterfaceEnabled:   "true"
```